# Python regular expression for number set and key word

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to find a pattern using re to find a sequence of numbers followed by some key words.

```
string =" 12390 total income stated in red followed by 567 total income stated in blue."
pattern = re.match("\s*\d{1,2}\s* total income",string)
```

I tried the *pattern*, but it is not good.
I want at the end to get these results: "12390 total income" and "567 total income".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `re.findall` and change the pattern `\d{1,2}` to `\d+` (*one or more digit chars*), since `\d{1,2}` should match a min of 1 and max of 2 digits only.

```
result = re.findall(r"\d+ total income",string)
```

Note that `match` tries to match from the begining of the string where `findall` should do a global match.

Answer (score 0):

If you have several space (say 1 or 2 etc) between *number* and *total income*  in that case use *non-capturing group construct*.

Say string is

```
string = '12390total income stated in red followed by 567      total income stated in blue.'
```

Then try as below

```
myresult = re.findall(r"\d+(?:\s*?total income)",string)
```

Extracts

```
['12390total income', '567      total income']
```

Then use `replace` to remove extra space.

```
enter code here
```